# Unable to get tinymce to work in django: AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'HTMLField'

Tags: python, django, docker, tinymce

I am trying to get this package to work in Django:
https://github.com/romanvm/django-tinymce4-lite

I'm using docker compose for my django installation. The setup is identical to this one here:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/

Earlier when I encountered similar errors it had to do with the pip package not being properly loaded in docker. Now, I have loaded the "django-tinymce4-lite" package as follows:

- I have edited my requirements.txt in my project
- I have rebuilt my docker image
- When I log onto the docker instance, I can check the presence of the package using this:

  $ pip freeze
  Django==2.0.6
  django-bootstrap3==10.0.1
  django-tinymce4-lite==1.7.1
  jsmin==2.2.2
  Pillow==5.1.0
  psycopg2-binary==2.7.4
  pytz==2018.4

This seems to be in line with my requirements.txt file:

```
Django>=2.0
psycopg2-binary
django-bootstrap3
django-tinymce4-lite
Pillow
```

However, when I follow the instructions I do this:

1. Add tinymce to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py for your Django project

   INSTALLED_APPS = (
       ...
       'tinymce',
   )
2. Add tinymce.urls to urls.py for your project:

   urlpatterns = [
       ...
       url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
       ...
   ]

NOTE: because I use Django 2 I have had to rewrite this. Here is what I use:

```
path('tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
```

I have tried this both in my main project urls.py as well as in my app urls.py. The next step is:

```
In your code:

from django.db import models
from tinymce import HTMLField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    content = HTMLField('Content')
```

However, the moment that I do this, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'HTMLField'
```

Anybody any idea how I could further debug/investigate this?

Comment: Check to make sure you haven't accidentally typed `models.HTMLField` somewhere; and try deleting any `*.pyc` files.

Comment: That was it, thanks @BurhanKhalid! The problem was a reference to `models.HTMLField` instead of HTMLField (without the models.!). Could you add this as an answer to confirm it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means you are trying to access the `HTMLField` attribute of the `models` class; so probably somewhere you have typed `models.HTMLField` by mistake.